# Alpha users of Action can't access Google Assistant directory listing or Action

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

Our Dialogflow agent is in Alpha release for Google Assistant. We've had a number of users whitelisted for the Alpha release who have been testing our agent for more than six months. Yesterday, suddenly many Alpha users couldn't invoke our agent from Google Assistant. Accessing the agent by its invocation phrase shows directory listings for a generic search based on the keywords in the phrase rather than invoking the Action. Exploring the directory on Google Assistant, shows the Action but the listing page is empty. Accessing the directory listing using the link from Manage Alpha Users page results in "We can't find what you're looking for at the moment. Please try again later" error message. Alpha users are present in the Actions Console Manage Alpha Users page. Google Assistant settings are all as per recommendations and in place for a number of months. Nothing has changed on our side. We've noticed inexplicable failures with Dialogflow and Google Assistant integration over the past couple of weeks. Many of these issue seem to surface and disappear on their own. However, currently Alpha user access is not working and seems to be a permanent state of affairs. Attached is the directory page listing that Alpha users see and the listing a developers see. Any assistance on resolutions is much appreciated.
[Screenshot with error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7HbHT.png).[Screenshot without error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBgoV.png).

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue since yesterday. Not only alpha testers, my developer account cannot access my action unless I enable test on device. My old/existing alpha testers cannot access the action even if I tried to remove them and added them back.

The only thing that I find for now is that if you add new test accounts (not old ones) to the whitelist, those new testers can access the action as usual.

Comment: I created a new user account and added it to Alpha user whitelist on Actions Console but the integration with Google Assistant is still broken. Users who have a test account using IAM for the cloud project are able to access the agent through Google Assistant and the directory page shows correct data.

Comment: Today the situation has improved but not back to working condition. Now the Alpha users can search for the Action and find the listing both on Google Assistant and on the Web. Send to Device button sends a notification to the phone. However, invoking the Action still doesn't work. It defaults to generic search. Very strange.

Comment: Yes, yesterday I was testing with a new tester account and the integration was working. However, as you mentioned, all the tester accounts can access the listing but cannot invoke the action correctly. I believe the problem is universal and can only be fixed by Google.

Comment: Thank you for confirming the behavior on your side. Why is no one from Google either commenting or presenting a resolution?

Answer (score 0):

Actions team seems to have fixed the issue in the last couple of hours. The problem is resolved and Alpha users are able to invoke and access our Action as before. We hope that Dialogflow integration with Actions on Google continues to be supported while developers consider migration to Actions Builder at their own pace.